# 「たなら」と「なら」についての質問

Tags: grammar, learning

> 「実はあのあとすぐに財布が見つかったの、モニターシステムがあったため。」
> 「な～んだ。そんなに簡単に○○、あちこち探すんじゃなかった。会社の中がひどい状態になったのよ。」
>
> A: 見つかるなら B: 見つかったなら

どちらが相応しい選択ですか？「見つかるなら」か「見つかったなら」か、または両方とも使えるのですか？

どう考えればいいですか？詳しく教えて頂けませんか？

Comment: 原文は「モニターシステムが**あったため** 。」で間違いないですか？

Comment: どうのように訂正すればよいですか？ぜひ教えて(●'◡'●)

Comment: 日本語学習用の問題集か何かから問題文を写したものだと思っていたのですが、問題集の原文が「あったため。」になっているということでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both A and B are correct, but there's a small difference.

> **A**: そんなに簡単に見つかるなら、あちこち探すんじゃなかった。
> If it was going to be found so easily, I shouldn't have looked around everywhere.

Here, the speaker temporarily places their point of view in the past, and is imagining the relative future from that point.

> **B**: そんなに簡単に見つかったなら、あちこち探すんじゃなかった。
> Since it was found so easily, I shouldn't have looked around everywhere.

Here, the speaker simply acknowledges that "it was found easily" is a fact. It's roughly the same as saying "In that case" in this context.

If I have to choose one, I personally prefer Sentence A because it sounds more vivid, but Sentence B is not incorrect or unnatural at all.

Comment: ご説明ありがとうございます。微妙なニュアンスは日本語勉強の楽しみと思います。

Comment: よく理解しました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: For sentence B in English, "Since" seems more natural than "If". "If that's the case" is a legitimate collocation (and probably more common than "Since that's the case"), but nowadays "In that case" is probably much more common.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you, corrected.